# Gradle clean task with bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin

Tags: java, gradle, docker, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to create a Gradle task that will run a clean, a build, and then run a buildDockerImage task from the bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin plugin. I can successfully run the clean task, build task, and buildDockerImage task in separate commands in the command line but when I try to create a singe task that does all three I get an error:

```
.../config-server/build/docker/state/DockerBuildImage_Decorated (No such file or directory)
```

It looks like the gradle-docker-plugin is trying to add some sort of log file to the /build/docker/state directory but that directory is not present when I run clean, build, and buildDockerImage in a single task. The directory is present however when I run these as separate commands in the CLI.

---

#### This Works

If I don't try to clean... it works correctly and the docker image gets created:

```
import com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.image.DockerBuildImage
task buildDockerImage(type: DockerBuildImage) {
  doFirst {
    copy {
      from 'src/main/resources/docker/Dockerfile'
      into 'build/libs'
    }
  }

  inputDir = project.file('build/libs')
  tag = alexFabian + "/" + jar.baseName
}

task myBuildDockerImage(type: Task, dependsOn: ['build' ,'buildDockerImage']) {
  buildDockerImage.mustRunAfter build
}
```

My build directory looks like :

```
/classes
/dependency-cache
/docker
/libs
/reports
/resources
/test-results
/tmp
```

---

#### This Fails

But when I add in a dependency on the 'clean' task... the buildDockerImage task fails because it can't find the /build/docker directory

```
import com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.image.DockerBuildImage
task buildDockerImage(type: DockerBuildImage) {
  doFirst {
    copy {
      from 'src/main/resources/docker/Dockerfile'
      into 'build/libs'
    }
  }

  inputDir = project.file('build/libs')
  tag = afabian + "/" + jar.baseName
}

task myBuildDockerImage(type: Task, dependsOn: ['clean', 'build' ,'buildDockerImage']) {
  build.mustRunAfter clean
  buildDockerImage.mustRunAfter build
}
```

Now my build/ directory looks like this (missing the /docker directory):

```
/classes
/dependency-cache
/libs
/reports
/resources
/test-results
/tmp
```

And I get this error :

```
Execution failed for task ':buildDockerImage'.
> .../config-server/build/docker/state/DockerBuildImage_Decorated (No such file or directory)
```

I've used Maven in the past and new to Gradle so my current understanding is limited.

- Using gradle (wrapper) : 2.11
- Using gradle-docker-plugin : com.bmuschko:gradle-docker-plugin:2.6.6

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why do you have a `doFirst` in your task?

Comment: speculating: Maybe your `copy` section is executing before the clean task? Try removing the `doFirst` from the copy part.

Comment: Good thought @RaGe. I tried removing the `doFirst` but the build fails and I get a `Directory .../build/docker specified for property 'inputDir' does not exist.` So I'm assuming without the do first the inputDir line gets executed before the copy is finished.

Answer (score 1):

It was a bug in earlier version of the bmuschko plugin.
Try with the new version. I was facing the same problem with an older version('com.bmuschko:gradle-docker-plugin:2.6.6'), but when I upgraded to version : com.bmuschko:gradle-docker-plugin:2.6.8  , it was fixed.

https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin/issues/168